# Gamma Correction for textures ripped from the Nintendo Switch

Tags: texturing, materials

I have some models that were ripped from the Nintendo Switch and most of the gammas on the diffuse textures are broken. I have no idea how to fix them.

Here are the models in question: https://mega.nz/folder/MVcmxK5Z#okChiYnaaEvGsmu_WxvmrA

If this is not the right place to ask, where would be a good site to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Blender comes with a powerful node-based image editor, the *Compositor*. You can do this in Blender. I list the steps to create the setup below, but depending on your situation, you may need to tweak the settings to get the output you want.

1. Switch to the *Compositor* workspace, and enable *Use Nodes*.
2. Add an image node (*Add > Input > Image*), and open your image. Blender sets the *Color Space* to sRGB by default. This is one of the settings you may need to tweak.
3. Add a *Convert Colorspace* node (*Add > Converter > Color Space*), and set the *From* and *To* fields based on your needs. Connect the nodes.
4. Set the *View Transform* to *Standard* under *Render Properties > Color Management*.
5. Set the resolution of the render to match your input image (*Output Properties > Format*).
6. Set the image output settings as desired (*Output Properties > Output*).

Now, if you press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render, the image will be processed and shown as the render.

[image: Steps]